# Converting existing log files to JSON format for analysis purposes

Tags: json, bigdata, logback, data-conversion

I'm looking into log analysis tools such as Splunk and elasticsearch/logstash. I modified my logback configuration so that it outputs all log as JSON, which can be routed to Splunk/logstash.

I have lots (GBs) of existing log files that I'd like to analyze. These files are in plain text. Anyone that knows of tools that can take a log file and the log pattern it is created with and use that to convert the log file to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think Logstash&elasticsearch are most suitable for you. Elasticsearch outputs the logs as JSON format.

Comment: I'm not asking which log analyzer I should use. I'm looking for something that can help convert my GBs of existing log files to JSON.

Comment: @verhage If the logs are consistent in format a small script could easily do this job for you.

Comment: You can use logstash filter to convert your logs to Json format. Logstash filter has many API for parsing the logs.